# how to make control over volume using java...?

Tags: java

Anyone have idea how to make control over volume.
I mean i want to make the volume control line in my music player.
Should i have to download javax.sound package.Currently i am using ubuntu please tell the command how to load javax.sound package in ubuntu...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javax.sound packages(1) are part of the J2SE (since 1.3).  If the JRE (or JDK) is installed, they will be available.

1) The most relevant classes for this task are in the [javax.sound.sampled package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html).